# test function within componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
componentWillMount() {
     // redux store
    CrudActions.getUsers();
}
```

How do I use jest to call my reducer? I want to write test for behavior instead of calling another the setAll function in CrudActions.

So far I'm only able to call the componentWillMount

```
test('calls `componentWillMount` before rendering', () => {
  const onWillMount = jest.fn();
  CrudList.prototype.componentWillMount = onWillMount;
  mount(<CrudList />);

  expect(onWillMount).toBeCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is here so I am interpretting it as "how can I unmount my component so that `CrudActions.getUsers()` is called?"

After mounting the component you can call [`unmount`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/unmount.md) to unmount it (I am assuming you are using enzyme to mount the component).

```
test('calls `componentWillUnmount` when unmounted', () => {
    const onWillUnmount = jest.fn();
    CrudList.prototype.componentWillUnmount = onWillUnmount;
    mount(<CrudList />).unmount();

    expect(onWillUnmount).toBeCalled();
});
```

So to call `CrudActions.getUsers()` just dont mock `componentWillUnmount` and it should call the actual function.